# How to fix Google Earth Engine image.getDownloadURL pixel grid dimensions limit

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I have created a small UI in which user will download the image when clicks on the download viewport button. But for some reason it gives me this error. How to fix it?

```
Line 15: Pixel grid dimensions (19814x15172) must be less than or equal to 10000.
```

This is my code : https://code.earthengine.google.com/f5a405d34b98023635ab463753939730

```
//demo
var col = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED");
var image = col.filterBounds(geometry).filterDate('2022-02-01','2022-02-28').filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE',10)).mosaic();
var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B8','B4']);

function downloadImg() {
  var viewBounds = geometry;
  var downloadArgs = {
    name: 'NDVI_App_Export',
    crs: 'EPSG:4326', // or 3857
    scale: 10,
    region: viewBounds.toGeoJSONString(),
    maxPixels:1e9,
};
var url = ndvi.clip(geometry).getDownloadURL(downloadArgs);
urlLabel.setUrl(url);
urlLabel.style().set({shown: true});
}

// Add UI elements to the Map.
var downloadButton = ui.Button('Download viewport', downloadImg);
var urlLabel = ui.Label('Download', {shown: false});
var panel = ui.Panel([downloadButton, urlLabel]);
Map.add(panel);

Map.addLayer(ndvi,{min:0, max:1, palette:['yellow','green']},'NDVI')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't fix it. The maximum dimension is a hard limit set in the function, it is not a parameter. The reason for the limit is that the function is using the [**Interactive** computing stack](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/processing_environments#interactive-environment), which is meant for small requests that complete quickly (they time out at 5 minutes). The max dimension is a little arbitrary, but a limit needs to exist to try to avoid firing up a request that will time out. The limit is stated in the [API reference docs](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-getdownloadurl).

Comment: I hear about this issue occasionally. I just did a feature request search but didn't find any open requests. I recommend you submit one for a solution to this problem of wanting to host an app where app users can download data that may be greater than the current limits (but still a reasonable sized image region).
https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/help#feature_requests

Comment: Indeed, I read a previous answer of yours and I understand it that get url is a client side function. I will have to use code editor and export to GDrive. Thank you Justin